# When i select a country, the list of state wouldn't change

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4, carmen

I use carmen-rails in my form to show country and sub-regions for each country, the first time when i select a country it update the list of subregions as well, then when i save these informations in database and go for the second time to above page and select another country it doesn't update the list of subregions !! then if reload page it does ! this is my js file in coffee-script format :

```
$ ->
  $('select#user_detail_attributes_country_code').change (event) ->

     select_wrapper = $('#user_detail_attributes_state_code')

     $('select', select_wrapper).attr('disabled', true)

     country_code = $(this).val()

     url = "/orders/subregion_options?parent_region=#{country_code}"
     select_wrapper.load(url)
```

note : I'm using **rails 4**, does rails 4 do some **caching** automatically and don't update the list ? or there is a problem with **change method in jquery** ? i can't find the problem here, any help please

my orders controller juste render a partial :

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def subregion_options
    render partial: 'orders/subregion_select'
  end

end
```

subregion partial code is :

```
div#order_state_code_wrapper
  - detail ||= params[:detail]
  - parent_region ||= params[:parent_region]
  - country = Carmen::Country.coded(parent_region) unless parent_region.nil?
  - if country.nil?
    %em Please select a country above
  - elsif country.subregions?
    = label_tag :user_detail_attributes_state_code, "State"
    = subregion_select_tag("user[detail_attributes][state_code]", detail.try(:state_code), parent_region)
  - else
    = label_tag :user_detail_attributes_state_code, "State"
    = text_field_tag("user[detail_attributes][state_code]", detail.try(:state_code))
```

**Edit**

i added **alert("foo")** inside jquery's change method, and when i select a country , sometimes it alert me "foo" and sometimes don't work !

Comment: what is the value returned by `"/orders/subregion_options?parent_region=#{country_code}"`

Comment: you need to sent `<option>dd</option<option>dd</option<option>dd</option` kind of response.... looks like you are sending a `div`

Comment: i don't think this is the problem, because i added alert("foo") inside change method of jquery, and when i select a country it don't show me the alert, i refresh again and it works, then i try again and it fails ...

Comment: can you share the related html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 turbo-link prevents jQuery scripts from working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769109/rails-4-turbo-link-prevents-jquery-scripts-from-working)

Comment: @ArunPJohny html use juste a helper form from carmen-rails there is no listed country, you can find an example of what it looks like here https://github.com/jim/carmen-rails, wait i show you my html

Comment: @muistooshort i think also that the problem is something like that, but can you tell me some steps to fix my problem please

Comment: @muistooshort your answer in the link isn't clear :(

Comment: `$(document).ready()` doesn't work with Turbolinks, `$ ->` is just another way of saying `$(document).ready()`, and Turbolinks is enabled by default in Rails4. You need to listen for different events (as noted in the linked answer) to initialize the page.

Comment: i think that problem is with change method not with $(document).ready(), i replace $ -> with $(document).on "page:change", ->  but don't work