# Rails not loading js in Chome from link_to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

My rails application does not seem to be loading some javascript behavior after being sent to a page via the link_to helper. This is happening in Chrome, but not IE (which hurts me to say). I've seen Chrome not loading behavior in multiple pages for bootstrap-switch, and for some custom functions that I have in my source tree. These **will** work after I reload the page from Chrome, but not off of the initial link_to.

Here is my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-switch
//= require jquery-placeholder
//= require jquery_nested_form
```

Is there some known limitation in how Chrome receives or renders javascript from the link_to helper? Please let me know if I can provide any additional information that will be helpful to resolve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 turbo-link prevents jQuery scripts from working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769109/rails-4-turbo-link-prevents-jquery-scripts-from-working)

Comment: Hi Mike, you're right; removing turbo-links resolved this issue. Can you move your comment into an answer so I can accept it, or is there another method by which I can confirm this is a duplicate?

Comment: I think it goes for moderator attention, but for what it's worth I'll post an answer incase the different wording attracts other folk struggling with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see from your `application.js` that you're using [turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).

When using turbolinks, `$(document).ready(function() { ..` is ignored when clicking on internal links because the page never actually reloads in the traditional way.

You have a couple of alternatives, rewrite/restructure your JS so that it plays nicely with turbolinks (by not having page-specific JS includes, by scoping your events appropriately, etc) or you can disable turbolinks if you don't want to use it by:

1. removing it from your `Gemfile`
2. remove the `//= require turbolinks` from your `application.js`
3. remove the 2 references to `"data-turbolinks-track" => true` in your `layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary, but in disabling turbolinks I also removed the 2 references to "data-turbolinks-track" => true in my layouts/application.html.erb.

Comment: whoops, yeah that too :).

Comment: Ya might need to remove it from the Gemfile too.