# Coffeescript doesn't always run

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

SO I've just started using coffeescript in a Rails 4 app and hitting a strange issue whereby the resultant js isn't always running

The only coffeescript I've written is a simple log statement:

```
$ ->
    console.log "show this"
```

This seems to pop up sporadically for first page loads. If it doesn't load and I refresh the page then it loads the following time.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it's caused by [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks).

```
$ ->
  console.log "show this"
```

means

```
$(function(){
  console.log("show this")
})
```

which means

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("show this")
})
```

Turbolinks intercepts the requests so that the `ready` event isn't triggered.

---

To solve this, you can either [disable Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#opting-out-of-turbolinks) or [use jquery-turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#jqueryturbolinks).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question: [Rails 4 turbo-link prevents jQuery scripts from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769109/rails-4-turbo-link-prevents-jquery-scripts-from-working)

You want to add a `page:change` event listener since Turbolinks suppresses `$(document).ready`

So something like this should fix the issue:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() { ... })
```