# Translating jQuery to Coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I posted a confusing question before.  Long story short, I have a bit of jQuery working close to the way I want, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work in CoffeeScript.

When I try it different ways in CS the "on search" event triggers as soon as the page is loaded.  I can't get it to just attach to the dataTable as I do in jQuery.

I'm sure it's something simple and dumb.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customers').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "aaSorting": [],
        "ordering": false
    } );

    $('#customers')
            .on( 'search.dt',  function () { $('.nested_indent').hide(); } )

} );
```

The most recent CS version is here (the one that trips every time the page loads.)

```
jQuery ->
    $('#customers').dataTable(
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
        "aaSorting": []
        "ordering": false
    ).$('#customers').on( 'search.dt',  
         $('.nested_indent').hide() )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 differences towards the end from the JavaScript version:

```
).$('#customers').on( 'search.dt',  
     $('.nested_indent').hide() )
```

The first is the `.` before `$('#customers')`. This attempts to use `$` as a method rather than a global. You'll want to remove the `.` and insert a line break with matching indentation.

The second is that the `function` that was around `$('.nested_indent').hide()` is missing. You'll have to include at least `->` to define one, as you have with `jQuery ->`.

```
)  # 1) separate statements with line break

$('#customers').on( 'search.dt', ->  # 2) wrap `hide` in a `function`
     $('.nested_indent').hide() )
```

---

The 2nd difference is why you're seeing:

> [...] the "on search" event triggers as soon as the page is loaded.

Without the `->`, the `.hide()` statement is being called immediately and its `return` value is being passed to `.on()`, so it isn't actually bound to the event.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that the event is getting triggered on page load, but that you are passing `$('.nested_indent').hide()` is getting run on page load because you are not passing it in a function in your CS as you are doing in your JavaScript.

What you want is:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#customers').dataTable(
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap"
        "aaSorting": []
        "ordering": false
    );  

    $('#customers').on 'search.dt', ->
         $('.nested_indent').hide()
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  This was driving me nuts.

Comment: @RobE. By the way, have you heard of this page: http://js2.coffee/  This "translator" works most of the time, just paste your javascript into the left side. and CS comes out on the right. In this example you get the exact same result as this answer.