# JS not running until second refresh of page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

Just what it says. I'm trying to do some simple drop down filtering with jquery, and my function doesn't get executed on page load. Here's what I've checked:

- added a console.log to verify
- used document.ready to call function
- It's getting loaded through sprockets in app.js
- it's listed in dev console, and I don't get any resource not found errors

Here's the crazy part : everything works perfectly after one refresh. Console.log comes back and reports the listener has been attached to the select element and everything is roses.

Any ideas why?

EDIT here's the entirety of the js (there may be a better way of doing this, also open to suggestions):

```
//unrelated JS


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#user_state_code option").unwrap();
  $state_copy = $("#user_state_code").children().clone(true);

  $("#user_country_code").change(function(){
    console.log("state filter called");
    filterStates($("#user_country_code").val());
  });

  $("#user_country_code").change();
});

function filterStates(countryCode){
  $("#user_state_code").html(
    $state_copy.get().filter(function(d){
      var currCountry = String(d.value);
      return currCountry.slice(0,2) == countryCode;
    })
  );
}
```

**Epilogue**

Here's what needed to be fixed (thanks to @Rain who put me in the right track, and prompted me to find this amazing resource: [Rails 4 turbo-link prevents jQuery scripts from working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18770219/2785476)

```
var ready = function() {
  $("#user_state_code option").unwrap();
  $state_copy = $("#user_state_code").children().clone(true);

  $("#user_country_code").change(function(){
    console.log("state filter called");
    filterStates($("#user_country_code").val());
  });
  filterStates($("#user_country_code").val());
};

function filterStates(countryCode){
  $("#user_state_code").html(
    $state_copy.get().filter(function(d){
      var currCountry = String(d.value);
      return currCountry.slice(0,2) == countryCode;
    })
  );
}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

Comment: Are you running it at `$(function() { -- all scripts are ready here });`? If not it could be a timing problem

Comment: You didn't post your code, so it's hard to say, but there's a good chance that you're trying to fetch something and not waiting for the HTTP transaction to finish.

Comment: No, I'm using '$(document).ready(function(){....' , I'm supposing it also waits until DOM is ready?

Comment: Yes, mine is the shorthand version :) So I agree with @Pointy post the code that fetches your javascripts, and where you are using the console.log at least

Comment: Why do you have change event on same element twice??
Try to catch the change event this way : $("#user_country_code").on("change", function(){}); 
This may be the problem that DOM is not loaded before running the script.
I would recommend you to put the JS at the end if you are not doing the same.

Comment: I had it twice to trigger the event as the select has to get filtered directly. I could call the function directly.