# I need to refresh for DropzoneJS to work with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I made a simple test application which uses DropzoneJS. I incorporated a Bootstrap navbar, and put the dropzone in one of the tabs. If i click on the tab the dropzone goes to fallback mode everytime. Only when I refresh the page it works again.

My code is as following:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  // disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

  var dropzone = new Dropzone (".dropzone", {
    maxFilesize: 256, 
    paramName: "image[avatar]", 
    addRemoveLinks: false 
  });

  dropzone.on("success", function(file) {
    this.removeFile(file);
    $.getScript("/images");
  })
});
```

My view is as following:

```
<h1>Upload image</h1>


<div class ="container">
<%= form_for(Image.new, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone"}) do |f|  %>
  <div class="fallback">
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Upload my Avatar" %>
  </div>
 </div>
<% end %>

<div class="index">
  <%= render "index" %>
</div>
```

Hope somebody can help me out!

Comment: Are you using `turbolinks`?

Comment: Good call, removing turbolinks from application.js fixes the issues. Are there any implications to not using turbolinks? Fairly new to Rails so not really sure what it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [jQuery Tubrolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem would be a quick fix.

Comment: This works, i'll try to find the underlying reasons as to why, but this worked. I would upvote it as well if i would have the rep, thanks!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769109/rails-4-turbo-link-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-position-of/18770219?noredirect=1#18770219) for more explanation