# Embedded Google Maps in Rails not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

I'm trying to embed Google Maps into my Ruby on Rails website.

I am able to search places on the map using a search feature I implemented, but I am unable to interact with the map in any way. I can't drag, zoom, click directions, click to change to satellite view -- nothing.

I have taken the standard code from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

I have confirmed it is a problem with Rails by writing a simple html file with the same exact code, and running a SimpleHTTP Python server. In this simple HTML file, the map is fully functional.

Is there something in Rails that is stopping this from working?

I'm running Ruby 2.2.1 and Rails 4.2.6

Refreshing the page, the console looks like this

```
Started GET "/homes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=name2&commit=Find" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400
Processing by HomesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"name2", "commit"=>"Find"}
  Home Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `homes`.* FROM `homes` WHERE `homes`.`name` = 'name2'  ORDER BY `homes`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered homes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 12.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started GET "/assets/turbolinks.self-c5acd7a204f5f25ce7a1d8a0e4d92e28d34c9e2df2c7371cd7af88e147e4ad82.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400


Started GET "/assets/homes.self-e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400


Started GET "/assets/jquery.self-660adc51e0224b731d29f575a6f1ec167ba08ad06ed5deca4f1e8654c135bf4c.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.self-e87806d0cf4489aeb1bb7288016024e8de67fd18db693fe026fe3907581e53cd.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400


Started GET "/assets/scaffolds.self-eb1a78b28e204749434f74792f8691befac84bd13affecbb8570043d2a38612c.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400


Started GET "/assets/application.self-d9e17b260b47ee1a5a805b39ec14012b484178bbc392ce717b7d51d0c785d7d3.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400


Started GET "/assets/homes.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400


Started GET "/assets/application.self-3b8dabdc891efe46b9a144b400ad69e37d7e5876bdc39dee783419a69d7ca819.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2016-07-08 16:07:00 -0400
```

Comment: Did you place your API key there?

Comment: Sounds like some conflicting javascript injected by Rails. Please check in your developers console what is included.

Comment: @Christian-G oh yes, sorry. I have added console code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a conflict of Rails's `turbolinks` with Google Maps, see this answer:

[Rails 4 turbo-link prevents jQuery scripts from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769109/rails-4-turbo-link-prevents-jquery-scripts-from-working/18770219#18770219)

See if turning off turbolinks fixes the problem:

- Remove `gem "turbolinks"` from your Gemfile and run `bundle`.
- Remove `//= require turbolinks` from `application.js`.