# Rails trouble sending AJAX data to controller

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm a AJAX rookie, so bear with me. I'm trying to send data from a chat-message box to two places -- the actual chat box and to a rails method. That way I can display the meesage, and also store the message in my DB.

I have the following JS/HTML code

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send">Try it</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("frm1");
      console.log(x);
      var text = "";
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < x.length ;i++) {
          text += x.elements[i].value + "<br>";
      }
      document.getElementById("chatbox").innerHTML += text;

      $.ajax({
            url : "/messages/create",
            type : "post",
            data : { data_value: x }
            dataType : "text" //this might be wrong?
      });

  }
</script>
```

I can successfully insert into the HTML DOM, but it isn't sending the data to the messages controller `create` action. My messages controllers is named `messsages_controller.rb` and the action is `create`.

I've added `debugger` in my `create` action in order to then view what `params` are, but it never even executes the code.

Some routes:

```
   messages GET    /messages(.:format)            messages#index
            POST   /messages(.:format)            messages#create
   new_message GET    /messages/new(.:format)        messages#new
  edit_message GET    /messages/:id/edit(.:format)   messages#edit
       message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)        messages#show
               PATCH  /messages/:id(.:format)        messages#update
               PUT    /messages/:id(.:format)        messages#update
               DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)        messages#destroy
```

**UPDATE**

wait, something is wrong with my JS code. It was previously inserting HTML into the DOM, but somewhere along adjustments it stopped. Now the console is throwing the error `new:110 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` line 110 is commented out.

When I the `.ajax` call out of the function, then it works fine. I have something syntactically wrong when I call the `.ajax` function inside `myFunction()`

Comment: What routes have you defined? Can you add codes for `create` method in your controller?

Comment: You're correct in your guess, `dataType` should be `json`.

Comment: @NicNilov that didn't resolve the issue. Am I correct in that if I place `debugger` in the `create` action, then it should open the debugger in the console? I have added routes

Comment: Depending on your setup, this is what might happen. Another option is using `binding.pry`. As @Kumar proposed you should add your routes to the question.

Comment: @Kumar I added `rake routes` there is no point in posting my `create` code because I haven't got that far. I want to verify data is being passed via `params` first by adding `debugger` in the `create` action -- and then verifying in the interactive ruby debugger.

Comment: Your routes look fine. Try changing `type: 'post'` to `method: 'post'`. Also, do you see any errors in browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url : "/messages", //by rails convention doing a post simply to '/messages' should be handled by create action
  method : "post",
  data : { data_value: x },
  dataType : "json", //this might be wrong?
  success: function(response){
    //do something,maybe notify user successfully posted their message
  },
  error: function(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

And in your `create` method you should handle `json` requests

```
def create
  //save message
  @message.save!
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { json: @message.as_json }
  end
end
```

This is how your code should look like. You can always do more creatively.

Please checkout this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kumarabinash/351ce825fec48e102aa3c6330aaa11dd)

Comment: `create` still isn't being executed -- verified by placing `debugger` as the first line in the `create` action

Comment: Did you pick up the `url : "/messages"` change?

Comment: Yes, please check update. something is wrong in my JS code now. Sorry, trying to multitask here... let me try some things

Comment: what's there in line 110?

Comment: please check the update -- I have something wrong when I call the `.ajax` function inside `myFunction()`. If I take the `.ajax` call out of the function, then the HTML insertion works fine, but when I add the `.ajax` call back it stops the insertion from working. do you think this is a rails issue?

Comment: One you're missing a comma after, `data : { data_value: x }`. Everything else seems to be fine. Can you update that and let me know if everything works?

Comment: the comma was the issue, now HTML insertion works. Now it's throwing error `new:106 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` line 106 is the ending of the ajax call `});`

Comment: That's jquery. Are you loading jquery? Please verify that in your `application.js` file

Comment: `//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .` I'm missing turbolinks because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274500/embedded-google-maps-in-rails-not-responsive?noredirect=1#comment63968495_38274500

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117126/discussion-between-kumar-and-kendall-weihe).