# Turbolink causing issue to load the 3rd party javascript(zendesk) on next page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, zendesk

I am on rails3, and Turbo-links causes the link for zendesk to not work.

I was using zendesk script and that was not loading on next page and then I have used script that mentioned [here](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/zendesk_web_widget.html). It seems working fine on chrome, but on Firefox and Safari, its still causing problem.

I have included below lines into my layout:

```
= javascript_include_tag 'zendesk', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true

:javascript
  document.addEventListener('page:change', zendesk_web_widget());

and zendesk_web_widget() is function that loading widget.
```

I have searched around web and found some solutions but not working at all:

> [Rails 4 turbo-link prevents jQuery scripts from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769109/rails-4-turbo-link-prevents-jquery-scripts-from-working/18770219#18770219)
>
> https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/166

Any anyone has any idea then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the return value of the function `zendesk_web_widget` to the listener, not the function itself. So instead of calling the function (with `()`), try passing the function:

```
document.addEventListener('page:change', zendesk_web_widget);
```

Or, making a wrapper function for it:

```
document.addEventListener('page:change', function () { zendesk_web_widget(); });
```

And since you're using jQuery, why not make the code use jQuery.

```
$(document).on('page:change', zendesk_web_widget);
```

Comment: Thanks Ollpu for  your response, but when I add wrapper function then it works into Firefox but not into Chrome, and reverse if I remove :(

Comment: Also make sure that the function is executed on initial page load, with something like `$(document).ready(zendesk_web_widget);`

Comment: thanks @ollpu, its helping me to run at one level ahead.