# Rails UJS confirm box cancel button callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ujs

I am using Rails [jquery ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) for handling ajax within my app. Also I am using a the `confirm` option for destroying any records.
As my current setup, I have hooked up a loading overlay screen on click of `data-remote=true` link.

All I wanted to know is: Is there a way I can hook a callback event when a user clicks `cancel` on the confirm box and I can close the loader overlay.

Comment: I don't know and don't think this is something worth research. "Cancel" is "cancel". It should not have any side effect. What you are going to do breaks usability.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. Pass in the response object. In CoffeeScript.

```
  $('selector').on 'confirm:complete', (e, response) ->
    if response
      # User confirmed
    else
      # User cancelled.
```

In Javascript:

```
  $('selector').on('confirm:complete', function(e, response) {
    if(response) {
      // User confirmed
    }
    else {
      // User cancelled.
    }
  });
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit It's a custom event from Rails UJS. See https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L280

Answer (score 3):

For those of you stumbling on this question and using Rails >= 5.1, note that the callback parameters have been bundled into `event.detail`, which is an array. The first callback parameter is `event.detail[0]` and so on.

To update Mohamad's answer, here's how to check the confirm value in Rails >= 5.1.

```
$('selector').on('confirm:complete', function(e) {
  if (e.detail[0]) {
    // User confirmed
  }
  else {
    // User cancelled.
  }
});
```

[From Rails Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers):

> Rails 5.1 introduced rails-ujs and dropped jQuery as a dependency. [...] Unlike the version with jQuery, all custom events return only one parameter: event. In this parameter, there is an additional attribute detail which contains an array of extra parameters.