# what is $.rails.confirm and how to implement it

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to customize the rails confirm box.  I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421072/jquery-ui-dialog-instead-of-alert-for-rails-3-data-confirm-attribute) that you can implement $.rails.confirm. I am a noob and have no idea of what that is.

Can anyone tell me how to use it to create custom alerts?